# Jhipster delting the languages

Tags: spring, internationalization, jhipster

I am really new to JHipster. I am writing an application based on the JHipster Template. The JHipster template comes up with a lot of languages but I only need a few of them. My question is how can I delete the other one without getting errors. I can't just delete the menu entries. Because they come from Cookies and are initialized with the following coed.

```
<li class="dropdown pointer" ng-controller="LanguageController">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">
                            <span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-tablet" translate="global.menu.language">Language</span>
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li active-menu="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key, language) in languages">
                                <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="changeLanguage(key)">{{language}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Does someone now where those Cookies are initialized and how I can delete the other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can delete them, indeed. Have a look at the constants.js file.
- In the next version we will make this easier, as indeed we are now having too many languages!

Comment: Answered on Chrostmas Eve, this makes me love jhipster even more than I thought was possible =) Thanks for a great generator and obviously great support!

Comment: You also need to change httpBackend.expectGET('i18n/sv.json').respond(200, ''); in serviceSpec.js